# Symfony2: Where to set a user defined time zone

Tags: php, symfony, timezone

One of my requirements for my current project is to allow a user to choose a time zone for their account, and then use this time zone for all date/time related features throughout the entire site.

The way I see it, I have two options:

- Pass in a DateTimeZone object to DateTime's constructor for every new DateTime
- Set the default time zone using PHP's `date_default_timezone_set()`

It seems like using date_default_timezone_set is the way to go, but I'm not sure exactly where I should set it.  Because the time zone will be different from user to user and DateTime's are used all over the site, I need to set it somewhere that it will affect all pages.

Maybe I could write an event listener that sets it after a successful login?  If I take this approach, will it stay set across all pages or is it only set on a per-page basis?

I'd love to hear how others would approach this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yea, you could use an event listener, hooking on the `kernel.request` event.

Here is the listener from one of my projects:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Bundle\AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Observe;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;

/**
 * @Service
 */
class TimezoneListener
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface
     */
    private $securityContext;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *     "securityContext" = @Inject("security.context"),
     *     "connection"      = @Inject("database_connection")
     * })
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface $securityContext
     * @param \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->connection      = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * @Observe("kernel.request")
     */
    public function onKernelRequest()
    {
        if (!$this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        if (!$user->getTimezone()) {
            return;
        }

        date_default_timezone_set($user->getTimezone());
        $this->connection->query("SET timezone TO '{$user->getTimezone()}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: @elnur, suppose that my server is set to "UTC" and the user to "America/Caracas". With your solution, what happens when a user submits a datetime in some entity field? Will the datetime be stored with the user timezone (with no changes compared to the value the user entered) or with the server timezone (value changed to match UTC time)?

Comment: @David You should only ever store UTC based times/dates in your database. That way you can always correctly format it for the user.