# Symfony 2: Global Database Query

Tags: php, symfony

How would I go about executing a database query on every page within a Symfony2 bundle?

I'm attempting to create a who's online functionality but this requires a query to be executed globally.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

If you only need it inside a view (probably layout) I suggest to create Twig Helper. You can have access to Doctrine in helper class. Check this link:

http://www.kiwwito.com/article/extending-twig-in-symfony-2-add-custom-functions

Answer (score 2):

You can render a sub-template, for example (in a project of mine) in my layout.html.twig I have this:

`{% render "EUPaNdataBundle:Home:listAllInstitutes" %}`

This will render a list of all institutes in a drop down menu in the top navigation bar.

`listAllInstitutes` is an action in the `Home` controller which gets a list of institutes from the DB and then returns the `listAllInstitutes.html.twig` template

Comment: Note that subrequests are very expensive in terms of performance.

Comment: How so? It's not doing a sub-request. It's not calling another page via HTTP; it's just including it. And in terms of performance, there are no problems. You could cache it anyway if you were to run into problems... How else would you render a list of institutes in a layout if you weren't to use a sub-template?

Comment: `include` is the one that just renders another template, while `render` does a sub-request. I write Twig extensions when I need to render something that needs to do a separate database query.

Comment: Yes, but it's an internal sub-request to a controller. Performance problems isn't going to be an issue. Although, writing a twig function to return an array of institutes would be a nice solution (for this scenario) If it's a more complicated scenario (involves lots of queries and quite a bit of html) then doing a sub-request is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create an event listener that listens for the `kernel.request` event and updates the current user's last seen time if she's logged in. See [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694315/symfony2-where-to-set-a-user-defined-time-zone/10699402#10699402) for an example of a listener and adapt it to your needs.