# Symfony2 user timezone

Tags: symfony, timezone

I am building a symfony2 app where the user can choose her timezone. I made the neseccary model/form changes to store a timezone field in the User object.

To apply the timezone inside a specific controller action I can just use:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
date_default_timezone_set( $user->getTimezone() );
```

Is there a way to do this without having to modify every controller/action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2: Where to set a user defined time zone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694315/symfony2-where-to-set-a-user-defined-time-zone)

Comment: @Gerry Yes I tryied it before asking but for some reason it didn't work. Nothing is getting called.

Comment: If nothing is called, make sure the listener is hooked to the `kernel.request` event: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but the same answer still applies.

`date_default_timezone_set` should not be used in this manner. If you create a `Datetime` instance, the timezone will always be set to symfonys default timezone. This will lead to inconsistencies, I wish you the best of luck finding them :)

Basically, you should create a custom `DateTime` type that handles conversion of timezones. Additionally, if you really want different timezone on your server, set the timezone in `config/parameters.yml` so php handles all dates in the timezone you need.

```
parameters:
    default_timezone: Europe/Warsaw
```

There's [a nice tutorial here](https://blog.bestcoding.net/en/symfony-doctrine-manage-user-timezone/) that will show you everything you need to know.